# Cannot understand what this code is doing

Tags: python

I am reviewing a practice code but cannot understand what this code is doing and how the final result is reached. It looks like much is a function but wow is an int, how could they be comparable? and why `wow = much(much(much))(wow)` returns 5.

```
wow = 6

def much(wow):
    if much == wow:
        such = lambda wow: 5
        def wow():
            return such
        return wow
    such = lambda wow: 4
    return wow()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `wow` is an integer, `much == wow` will fail and the function errors out, as `wow()` fails if `wow` is not a callable.

If `much == wow`, the function will define a new function `wow()` that returns the result from `such = lambda wow: 5`, which will always return `5`, as per definition.

If `wow` is a callable, but not the same function as `much`, the function just returns the result from `wow()`. `such = lambda wow: 4` is discarded completely.

`much(much(much))` basically returns `lambda wow: 5`, which returns 5, regardless of input, as `wow` is not used in the return value.

Odd function.